# Barryvdh\DomPDF how to break page inside a table

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I use Barryvdh\DomPDF to create my pdf from a "laravel" view.

I want to get the same title on each page. To do that, my code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Liste des personnes</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        .header,
        .footer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        position: fixed;
        }
        .header {
        top: 0px;
        }
        .footer {
        bottom: 0px;
        }
        .pagenum:before {
        content: counter(page);
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        {{-- -------------------------------------------------------- --}}
        {{-- pour ajouter une entete et un pied de page au pdf généré --}}
        {{-- -------------------------------------------------------- --}}

        <div class="header">
            <h2>Liste des personnes</h2>
            <hr>    
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Page <span class="pagenum"></span>
        </div>
        <div style="page-break-after:always;">
        
        <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top:30mm">
            <tbody>
                
                @foreach($liste_personnes as $personne)

                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <img style="height: 100px"  src="{{ asset($personne->nom_photo_vignette) }}" alt="pas de photo">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <strong>{{ $personne->nom.' '.$personne->prenom }}</strong><br>
                        {{ $personne->adresse1 }}<br>
                        {{ $personne->code_postal.' '.$personne->commune }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        né(e) le {{ $personne->date_naissance_dmY }}<br>
                        {{ $personne->libelle_role }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the result is this one :

[image]

As you can see, the header and footer are fine on the 1st page .But not for the next pages.

How to add some spaces for each new first row on each new page?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved like that :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Liste des personnes</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        @page { margin: 100px 50px; }
        .header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -100px; right: 0px; height: 100px; text-align: center; }
        .footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -50px; right: 0px; height: 50px;text-align: center;}
        .footer .pagenum:before { content: counter(page); }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        {{-- -------------------------------------------------------- --}}
        {{-- pour ajouter une entete et un pied de page au pdf généré --}}
        {{-- -------------------------------------------------------- --}}
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Liste des personnes</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            
            Page <span class="pagenum"></span>
        </div>
        
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                
                @foreach($liste_personnes as $personne)
                
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <img style="height: 80px"  src="{{ asset($personne->nom_photo_vignette) }}" alt="pas de photo">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <strong>{{ $personne->nom.' '.$personne->prenom }}</strong><br>
                        {{ $personne->adresse1 }}<br>
                        {{ $personne->code_postal.' '.$personne->commune }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        né(e) le {{ $personne->date_naissance_dmY }}<br>
                        {{ $personne->libelle_role }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]